# Java BufferedReader getting index of text file

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I already have this code that reading data from my text file. But how can I get the specific index or value from the text file?
I have text file that looks like this. For e.g I want to get the 3rd value or 4th value of text file which is 'test' or 'check'. Thanks in advance! Any help would be appreciated

> hello,world,test,check,online

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Readtxt {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
    String line = null; 

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] values = line.split(",");
      for (String str : values) {
        System.out.println(str);
      }
    }
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your variable `values` holds an array. Do you know how to get the 3rd value out of an array?

Comment: Splitting the string by commas is what gave you the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the values in the values array, you can get the n'th value using values[n-1].

Comment: I get it now, thanks! I stored the value of values array in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 3;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] values = line.split(",");
  for (String str : values) {
    if(str.equals("check")||str.equals("test")){
        count--;
        if(count==0){
            System.out.println("you got it!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

I think what you want should be like this. Define a counter to count how many qualified values you have passed.